# Filtering a list of nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am receiving the following response in a list of nested dictionaries format:

```
list_of_dicts = [{
        'id': '11593636317',
        'properties': {
            'created_date': '2021-09-28T16:16:31.635Z',
            'modified_date': '2021-09-28T16:16:31.635Z',
            'note': 'Test Note 123',
            'id': '11593636317'},
        'created_date': '2021-09-28T16:16:31.635Z',
        'updated_date': '2021-09-28T16:16:31.635Z',
        'archived': False
    },
    {
        'id': '11593636318',
        'properties': {
            'created_date': '2021-09-28T16:16:31.635Z',
            'modified_date': '2021-09-28T16:16:31.635Z',
            'note': 'Ticket Note',
            'id': '11593636318'},
        'created_date': '2021-09-28T16:16:31.635Z',
        'updated_date': '2021-09-28T16:16:31.635Z',
        'archived': False
    }
]
```

However, I don't need all of the records for a specific action. For that, I am trying to filter all records which `note` fields starts with the word `Ticket`.

```
For that I tried:
filtered_notes = []
for note in list_of_dicts:
    if note['properties']['note'].startswith('Ticket'):
        filtered_notes.append(note['id'])
```

Unfortunately, I am running into the following error and I have no clue how to get around it:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Comment: didn't you mean `note['properties']['note'].startswith('Ticket')`?
in case not all `'properties'` contain a `'note'` key you could also use `note['properties'].get('note', '').startswith('Ticket')`.

Comment: Just fixed the snippet, thanks! However even with your solution, I am running into the same error

Comment: Do `.get` for properties too.

Comment: @Vishnudev the issue still happens. for some records, I unfortunately have a value None on the 'note' key. Hence the error

Comment: After using `.get` for accessing all the values it should work. Check you code. @HeberBrandao

Comment: `.get()` can take two arguments; the second one is what will be returned if the key is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
filtered_notes = []
for note in list_of_dicts:
    try:
        if note['properties']['note'].startswith('Ticket'):
            filtered_notes.append(note['id'])
    except (KeyError, AttributeError):
        pass
```

The `try/except` block will protect you in case some of the needed keys are missing or the `note` property values has an unexpected type.

Comment: why not just `(note['properties'].get('note') or ‘’).startswith('Ticket')`, ie withiut try catch?

Comment: Indeed. If all items in the list have the `properties` key and `note` can only be a `str` or `None`, your solution works.